# Vue3 binding and refresh not working in multiple instances of same component

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have multiple instances of the same component in a list (or indeed, in a v-for array). Regardless of the order that I put these instances, it is always the first one in the list where data is displayed (data is loaded internally to the component using useLazyFetch from a different endpoint). I have copied the component code and renamed it, and this then 'works' (e.g. each component instance correctly pulls in data). `onMounted` is called, however `refresh` does not trigger the useLazyFetch (no network request happens). When using the 'filter' in the component after it's loaded, refresh is later called, but the binding does not work in subsequent components.

It feels like some oddity in Nuxt/vite/vue that it's somehow caching the component, but from what I've read you have to explicitly cache.

Parent component:

```js
<template>
    <div class="bg-white shadow-lg rounded-sm border border-slate-200 p-5 min-w-fit h-fit">
      <div v-for="(filter, ix) in listFilters" :key="ix"> 
        <ListFilter :id="ix" :filter-type="filter.type" :filter-endpoint="filter.endpoint" :endpoint="props.endpoint" @trigger-filter-change="handleChildFilter" @filter-change="onChildFilterChange"/>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

  const router = useRouter()
  const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();

  const emit = defineEmits(['filterChange', 'triggerFilterChange'])

  const listFilters = ref([
    {type: 'Medium', endpoint: 'media'}, {type: 'Support', endpoint: 'supports'}, { type: 'Pigment', endpoint: 'pigments'}, 
  ])
</script>
```

Child component:

```js
<template>
    
        <!-- Group 3 -->
        <div :id="props.filterType">
          <div class="flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
            <span class="text-sm text-slate-800 font-semibold mb-3">
              {{props.filterType}}
            </span>
            <span class="mb-3"><SmallSpinner v-if="pending"/></span>
          </div>
          <form class="relative mb-3">
            <label for="profile-search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
            <input class="form-input w-full pl-9 focus:border-slate-300" type="search" placeholder="Filter..." v-model="filterText"/>
            <button class="absolute inset-0 right-auto group" type="submit" aria-label="Search">
              <svg class="w-4 h-4 shrink-0 fill-current text-slate-400 group-hover:text-slate-500 ml-3 mr-2" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M7 14c-3.86 0-7-3.14-7-7s3.14-7 7-7 7 3.14 7 7-3.14 7-7 7zM7 2C4.243 2 2 4.243 2 7s2.243 5 5 5 5-2.243 5-5-2.243-5-5-5z" />
                <path d="M15.707 14.293L13.314 11.9a8.019 8.019 0 01-1.414 1.414l2.393 2.393a.997.997 0 001.414 0 .999.999 0 000-1.414z" />
              </svg>
            </button>
          </form>

         
          <ul :id="`list_` + props.filterType">
           
           <li v-for="(f, index) in listFilters" :key="f.id">
              <label class="flex items-center" v-if="index < 30">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" :id="f.id" :value="f.id" v-model="selectedIds" />
                <span class="text-sm text-slate-600 ml-2">{{f.filter_name}}</span>
              </label>
              <span v-if="index == 31">
                ...
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
       
</template>

<script setup>
  import {vAutoAnimate } from '@formkit/auto-animate'
  const router = useRouter()
  const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();

  const emit = defineEmits(['filterChange', 'triggerFilterChange'])

  const listFilters = ref([])
  const selectedIds = ref([])
  const urlQueryString = ref('')  
  const filters = ref([])
  const filterText = ref('')
  
  const uniqueId = Math.random().toString(8).slice(2)

  const props = defineProps({
    endpoint: String,
    filterEndpoint: String,
    filterType: String,
    appliedFilters: String
   })

  const timeout = ref(null)

  const {data, error, pending, refresh } = await useLazyFetch(() => {
    return `${props.endpoint}/${props.filterEndpoint}?${props.appliedFilters == undefined ? "" : props.appliedFilters}${urlQueryString.value}&id=${uniqueId}`
  }, { baseURL: runtimeConfig.public.baseURL, headers:{'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'} } )


  watch(data, (newData) => {
    console.log("LISTFILTER")
    console.log(data.value)
    
    if(data.value) {
        //console.log(data.value[props.filterType].length)
        console.log("Setting data to lFilters")
        listFilters.value = data.value[props.filterType]
    }
  })

  const triggerFilterChange = (filter) => {
    if (props.filterType == filter.type) {
      const ix = selectedIds.value.indexOf(filter.id)
      if (ix !== -1) {
        selectedIds.value.splice(ix, 1)
        emitFilterChange()
      }
    }  
  }

  onMounted(async () => {    
    // send the trigger to the parent.
    console.log("On Before mount")
    console.log(props.filterEndpoint)
    await refresh()
    emit('triggerFilterChange', { type: props.filterType, fn: triggerFilterChange} )
    
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in an online playground like stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that both the binding issues I was experiencing and the missing network calls were down to not providing a `key` on the `useLazyFetch` method, e.g.

```
const {data, error, pending, refresh } = await useLazyFetch(() => {
    return `some_endpoint`
  }, { baseURL: runtimeConfig.public.baseURL, headers:{'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}, key: `my-unique-id` } )
```

As otherwise the key is generated according to the filename.